# JPA OneToMany only persists one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this code:

```
@Table(name = "Prize")    
public class Prize {
    @Id
    @Column(
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) 
    private Set<TicketNumber> numbers;

}

@Table(name = "TicketNumber") 
public class TicketNumber {
    @Id
    @Column(
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    private int id;
}
```

This creates a join table called Prize_TicketNumber with two fields (Prize_id and TicketNumber_id) but when I save a prize with many numbers, only one record is inserted in said table. Does anyone know why?

EDIT: This is the code of the insertion. The repositories are simple JpaRepositories.

```
Prize prize = prizeRepository.findById(prizeId);
if(prize == null) return;
List<TicketNumber> winners = ticketNumberRepository.findByPrizeId(fixedPrize.getId());
if (winners != null && !winners.isEmpty()) {
    for (TicketNumber winner : winners) {
        winner.setWinner(false);
        TicketNumber t = ticketNumberRepository.save(winner);
    }
    raffleNumberRepository.flush();
}
prize.getTicketNumbers().clear();
for (String ticketId : ids) {
    TicketNumber ticketNumber = ticketNumberRepository.findOne(ticketId);
    if (ticketNumber != null) {
        ticketNumber.setWinner(true);
        prize.getTicketNumbers().add(raffleNumber);
    }
}
prize.setNumbersAssigned(true);
prizeRepository.saveAndFlush(prize);
```

Comment: Post your code. The code doing the insertion of ma,y numbers, and the whole code of the two entities.

Comment: Did u try to use List instead of Set ? Maybe you have problem with equals

Comment: I bet it's equals and hashCode too

Comment: I don't think it's equals and/or hashcode, because the set contains all the correct objects just before doing the save.
@JBNizet I posted the code of the insertion. The entities dont have much more code, just getters and setters and uninteresting stuff.

Answer (score -2):

A one-to-many association should not need a join table. On a one-to-many association the child should hold the id for the parent.

It looks like you are missing the parent id on your child and hibernate is assuming this is a many-to-many association and then creating the join table.

Comment: No. A join table is the specified default mapping for a unidirectional one-to-many association, and for valid reasons. And that doesn't answer the question anyway.

Comment: You mention there is a good reason for a join table for a on-to-many - could you share your opinion why having an additional table is beneficial in this case? Also, my suggestion is that changing the mapping might fix the issue, but I understand that might not have been totally clear.

Comment: If it's unidirectional, that means the many side shouldn't know about the one side. Having a column in the many side table to materialize this association defeats the purpose.

Comment: Interesting, not sure I agree but appreciate the different perspective. A many-to-one association does not define the directionality of the relationship, but rather the relationship between the different entities. One-to-many can be either unidirectional or bidirectional - it depends on whether you care about the "belongs to" or the "owns many" part of the association. Also, from a performance perspective, join tables are certainly more expensive than direct relationships.